# How to fix access denied issue on aws S3 with API deployed on port 443 trying to read the s3 objects

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-denied

I have a Restful API (asp .net 4.5.2) deployed on EC2 instance and EC2 instance is having IAM role for accessing S3 bucket (full access to bucket).
Now when I am trying to read the objects in bucket, it is returning Access Denied (403) in response and when I am trying to upload any attachment via pre-signed url, it is returning AWS signature mismatch in response when my API is deployed on port 443 but it is working fine when API is deployed on any other port like 80/81 and bucket is accessible through aws-cli.
Any idea why it might be happening?

my code snippets for reading objects:

```
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion))
{
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
BucketName = bucketName,
MaxKeys = 10
};
ListObjectsV2Response response;

response = s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request).Result;
            // Process the response.
            foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
            {
                keyValuePairs.Add(entry.Key, entry.Size);
            }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the IAM policy granting full access to the bucket ?

Comment: IAM role already has full access to S3 bucket.

Comment: Is your instance in a VPC?

Comment: I appreciate your IAM policy grants full access to the bucket, but still, can you share the exact JSON ? minor typos and the use (or lack of) of "/*" can cause the symptoms you're describing.

Comment: @hephalump : if this was a network issue, the code would not return 403

Comment: thanks every one for your response. IAM policy has not any issue. I need to pass the InstanceProfileAWSCredentials profile while instantiating s3Client object and it solved my problem. (adding complete code below.)

Comment: @hephalump: yes, my EC2 instance is in VPC.

Answer (score 1):

I need to pass the InstanceProfileAWSCredentials profile while instantiating s3Client object and it solved my problem.

```
var profile = new InstanceProfileAWSCredentials();
using (var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(profile, bucketRegion))
{
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
BucketName = bucketName,
MaxKeys = 10
};
ListObjectsV2Response response;

response = s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(request).Result;
        // Process the response.
        foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects)
        {
            keyValuePairs.Add(entry.Key, entry.Size);
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be an issue related to your security group on EC2 instances. you have to open port 443 (HTTPS). if this does not work the issue is related to port being in use by another application. check all your services that uses port 443.

Comment: S3 instance is independent of EC2 instance, its security is based on the bucket policy